# What does "process changes its effective UID or GID" mean in the cgrulesengd man page?

Tags: cgroups

I am planning to user cgrules.config to move processes stared by a user to my cgroup. The man page(https://linux.die.net/man/8/cgrulesengd) of cgrulesengd says that any time a process changes its effective UID or GID it is invoked and moves the process based on the config. But what does the statement "process changes its effective UID or GID" exactly mean. Does it include all the scenarios when a process is started i.e. any new process will be moved based on config.

I have been playing with some configs and found out that yes, new processes do get moved but want to make sure as it is not clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should read https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html

> Effective user ID and effective group ID.  These IDs are used
> by the kernel to determine the permissions that the process
> will have when accessing shared resources such as message
> queues, shared memory, and semaphores.  On most UNIX systems,
> these IDs also determine the permissions when accessing files.
> However, Linux uses the filesystem IDs described below for
> this task.  A process can obtain its effective user (group) ID
> using geteuid(2) (getegid(2)).

Note, in the majority of the cases, the effective UID of a process is equal to the real UID. But this may change when executing a set-uid executables.

For example, when executing `su user`, the effective uid is changed with root, then `su` has the possibility to change the uid to the specified user. But the real uid is checked, since a normal user can't `su` without giving a password.